# Transparent Polygon not being drawn in R 4.1.2? (but is drawn in R 4.0.3)

Tags: r, polygon, transparent

I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this?

I was re-running an old script in R 4.1.2 that had worked correctly in R 4.0.3 and was baffled by some transparent filled polygons not being drawn in the plots. After closer investigation, if the fill colour of the polygons were changed to a non-transparent colour (I was using the "adjustcolor" function, so I just changed the "alpha" option to equal 1) the polygons would however be drawn.

The following code examples will hopefully illustrate the problem - I am including a specific set of x,y coordinates giving me the problem (as I wonder if the specific complexity or shape of the polygon is part of the issue?)

running this in R 4.0.3

```
time=seq(0,360,by=1)

lower=c(0,9.808413838,16.73164571,18.76349566,18.39009377,17.02697093,15.841783,14.40087799,13.44195299,12.33561621,10.81540015,9.483312805,7.772220814,26.52906075,28.47845246,27.2619361,25.99168124,24.41197181,21.92306555,19.37183496,16.98551416,14.89342689,12.78656155,10.35230535,8.379609529,19.23918021,17.56574333,16.96574759,15.48243068,13.96697171,12.15929731,10.49247456,8.739319275,7.019079443,5.62710167,4.504181154,3.659087275,15.55871575,14.38943941,13.67748891,12.79299843,11.49848585,10.09104001,8.779516045,7.59585163,6.39048855,5.12093291,4.098618087,3.277594375,14.69391639,13.73897617,12.79468771,12.07063769,10.65682969,9.286941718,8.015166137,6.916478565,5.765415956,4.577256813,3.615388525,2.85415718,14.23825007,13.45717759,12.61987982,11.88914909,10.38071466,9.064098314,7.822741548,6.75030935,5.673792771,4.538753087,3.585044609,2.829329539,14.07813214,13.21393248,12.27663099,11.3946419,10.0191356,8.643706628,7.400416609,6.322833357,5.216156272,4.085693947,3.186810227,2.482541615,13.79301681,13.02451854,12.14948757,11.26249433,9.85974012,8.509470463,7.285462798,6.239612509,5.15732224,4.057991935,3.165265425,2.465489432,13.67019144,12.80324751,11.82771572,10.80004119,9.539992631,8.130486693,6.906005578,5.809265297,4.662903175,3.656752502,2.816776712,2.166464812,13.29163314,12.64020931,11.72166635,10.68866272,9.405388881,8.018218732,6.810824409,5.748154362,4.621878498,3.635726524,2.800635347,2.154070051,13.14083827,12.43063765,11.41735337,10.34778747,9.090105356,7.665861878,6.465622063,5.336040273,4.176715721,3.268006713,2.494918602,1.903210523,13.05748144,12.28903912,11.32830719,10.21091475,8.976876914,7.570441091,6.385254864,5.295802489,4.145233249,3.243382305,2.482784428,1.888787068,12.91746197,12.08635429,11.03947335,9.95916774,8.655292565,7.241351112,6.064677001,4.840125361,3.746561123,2.898820495,2.214058495,1.710402991,12.75826178,11.96321316,10.96436563,9.839597279,8.557927824,7.159948195,5.996593755,4.806818289,3.720796451,2.878896528,2.204916035,1.699038473,12.62867702,11.77195167,10.68951368,9.601906021,8.254773767,6.857114381,5.697973305,4.394775862,3.363139658,2.572307266,1.967380334,
        1.501234263,12.38578403,11.66420086,10.62612083,9.497114911,8.17080331,6.787435364,5.640152024,4.37043521,3.344520684,2.558078722,1.956504468,1.492699679,12.26939161,11.48022213,10.36411335,9.271817581,7.884156682,6.50324234,5.277289723,3.990264544,3.016518293,2.280548458,1.750173056,1.317093039,12.14751232,11.38731851,10.31028995,9.179781506,7.81159112,6.443459157,5.250539845,3.970013026,3.001049123,2.268874016,1.744983776,1.306614005,12.06035203,11.20981234,10.06010246,8.966946699,7.539857826,6.175632453,4.853333824,3.628141193,2.713359341,2.068709549,1.557875714,1.174585372,11.96878509,11.12938629,10.0143305,8.885907081,7.477038777,6.124251218,4.831890392,3.612065593,2.701238472,2.059110468,1.553932576,1.166263989,11.88469849,10.95757123,9.774793319,8.681525483,7.220171843,5.871305363,4.470292036,3.304181511,2.45540786,1.905969062,1.388797173,1.049200441,11.80387139,10.8854499,9.735699353,8.610313333,7.165568345,5.82706986,4.453361903,3.291643105,2.445262757,1.89821737,1.38568409,1.042485695,11.72243174,10.71861504,9.517479086,8.414867943,6.925553127,5.587745592,4.119464393,3.009868173,2.28547583,1.757736182,1.241279051,0.938078818,11.64044168,10.65434568,9.472502662,8.351797851,6.878099368,5.549607215,4.105653264,2.999737652,2.277101741,1.751881,1.23899594,0.932613544,11.57175714,10.49209428,9.287952554,8.164481211,6.649091841,5.257391429,3.799446568,2.775234675,2.12997825,1.590491902,1.111079106,0.839303237,11.46549158,10.4365872,9.223098009,8.108670731,6.607799624,5.242461177,3.788661351,2.766158165,2.123182548,1.588045554,1.109244026,0.834988343,11.40053157,10.27859688,9.072397615,7.928751173,6.388968935,4.905238095,3.505043788,2.611309117,1.98733038,1.441269475,0.995783544,0.75156961,11.30406599,10.22963857,9.010823429,7.879263189,6.352998085,4.893427179,3.496602946,2.603793181,1.981761313,1.439237889,0.994377054,0.748090146,0.567241261,0.394235453,0.274734085,0.191506461,0.136819214,0.102492417,0.076809002,0.05757791,0.043211435,0.03245718,0.024380428,0.0179901,0.013068467,0.009490345,0.006895657,0.005014055,0.003645662,0.002648651,0.001923437,0.001397503,0.001016078,0.00073862,0.000535927,0.00038477)

upper=c(0,69.5831179,68.95384572,65.19871687,63.07577135,58.42865679,57.12603158,52.54380606,49.80408744,47.1150641,44.57133065,42.50061429,40.12088379,103.424341,104.3845494,98.89831002,91.34843181,88.84275747,84.27690912,81.01326165,76.27023447,73.44058199,70.71161721,68.04732037,65.44032643,87.45554273,85.06801642,79.7651964,75.40844245,72.05345779,68.92556376,65.42942743,61.75284589,58.02698326,54.34382546,52.84792331,51.42992262,75.16729319,72.65102945,68.84323484,65.09182036,61.52029261,59.36494361,57.77386683,56.22515382,54.71824955,53.25206966,51.82558844,50.4378052,68.76602884,66.77372286,63.15917145,61.4114633,59.68395169,57.99753756,56.35678013,54.76218733,53.21302921,51.70803198,50.2269393,48.134254,64.36181471,64.20492356,61.68563857,59.98131512,58.29587399,56.65025739,55.04906445,53.49284177,51.83784643,49.67908545,47.6101092,45.62760452,62.85774639,62.79427979,60.38113463,58.62263405,56.88725923,55.19578325,53.55261705,51.39042376,49.13824363,47.16453174,46.17045897,45.19746231,61.27936266,61.4518984,58.87235611,57.15947146,55.46830646,53.81967871,51.79142852,49.5275121,47.9177436,46.90815091,45.91986835,44.95252799,60.07617068,60.07271883,57.5673766,55.80611757,54.07075266,52.26734316,49.88358797,48.32564824,47.25585014,46.2095179,44.89292001,43.51016856,58.51300191,58.28929641,56.10838671,54.39302113,52.70208394,50.77446337,48.76534571,47.68720386,46.54794077,45.14959263,43.76928012,42.27209698,57.36343872,57.05040503,54.86599819,53.10625386,51.37506434,49.28146501,47.90665842,46.60013805,45.13259089,43.69412909,42.26887464,40.49035876,55.89571938,55.58915546,53.50024116,51.78535869,50.09753748,48.17001319,46.93674103,45.45862915,44.02718542,42.60569483,41.21596336,39.4557192,54.8328106,54.56457113,52.34925508,50.59271573,48.86733765,47.21183505,45.66074309,44.15653969,42.69243559,41.23545996,39.73212956,37.89445351,53.47851817,53.29339,51.09255541,49.37913327,47.69537412,46.08972382,44.57149957,43.10326886,41.66674364,40.24475049,38.80509503,37.01027617,52.51175986,52.40094238,50.04065186,48.28749161,46.56808449,44.93851523,43.39302923,41.90069023,40.42780704,38.98735562,37.41389322,35.60777089,
        51.30159646,51.2627496,48.89308183,47.18100591,45.50119383,43.90853978,42.3985256,40.94043231,39.49999382,38.09256367,36.60021508,34.83333874,50.7351443,50.4658534,47.93672679,46.18636323,44.51055451,42.85259118,41.31679903,39.83605288,38.36581933,36.94124287,35.3335624,33.55654161,49.7637448,49.43261039,46.8907618,45.17941649,43.56552618,41.91491291,40.41274647,38.96441547,37.52809435,36.13458273,34.60987625,32.86921435,49.24840226,48.71211684,46.0215309,44.27308819,42.65277469,40.9475555,39.42079796,37.95097972,36.48863922,35.07906893,33.44720674,31.69768183,48.35383707,47.76695908,45.06707824,43.35567734,41.76143678,40.09420351,38.59926686,37.16007812,35.73136168,34.35100458,32.79851973,31.08288885,47.89163697,47.11085668,44.27529294,42.52783649,40.90546502,39.20666414,37.68815526,36.22848067,34.77600144,33.38054462,31.72538683,30.00216038,47.06882018,46.24206451,43.40152396,41.68929446,40.07571614,38.49503705,36.93988943,35.50918527,34.08921341,32.72127616,31.14079892,29.44929015,46.64917673,45.64109217,42.67754328,40.93022418,39.28040633,37.67539487,36.10034031,34.65006428,33.20779036,31.82564245,30.14604325,28.44814687,45.88871596,44.8394584,41.87484116,40.16109102,38.51291531,37.03828062,35.41679941,33.99396952,32.58274311,31.22657312,29.61701944,27.94888534,45.50555999,44.2923426,41.21025376,39.46232203,37.7768702,36.27466594,34.64048329,33.19784048,31.76645627,30.39691112,28.69157303,27.01818763,44.80063562,43.75881127,40.47017228,38.75430117,37.08404461,35.68983062,34.01400367,32.59850933,31.19553653,29.85056985,28.21113878,26.56574192,44.44935087,43.32040092,39.85769954,38.10851161,36.40908135,34.97602751,33.29358419,31.85785362,30.43680458,29.07925528,27.34742269,25.6978364,43.79426015,42.81507034,39.33241158,37.4544847,35.78434927,34.43769277,32.71749864,31.30887793,29.91351121,28.5792679,26.90975287,25.28653622,23.76165468,22.32814478,20.95200122,19.64681864,18.42459558,17.27927326,16.22289482,15.248767,14.33347408,13.4734914,12.66548077,11.90629053,11.19292688,10.52260887,9.892751818,9.300912878,8.744781708,8.222186384,7.731091567,7.269588774,6.855227294,6.535482722,6.230707621,5.940198023)

plot(time, upper, col='white', ylab='random',  log='y')

polygon( c(time, rev(time)),
         c(lower, rev(upper)), 
         col=adjustcolor('dodgerblue', alpha=0.25), border=NA)
```

gives the following plot

[4.0.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vzep.png)

running in R 4.1.2 gives the following (polygon apparently not drawn)

[4.1.2_plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7spNn.png)

...but changing the polygon fill color to non transparent as follows,

```
polygon( c(time, rev(time)),
         c(lower, rev(upper)), 
         col=adjustcolor('dodgerblue', alpha=1), border=NA)
```

does draw the polygon

[4.1.2_plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI8EB.png)

If a simpler polygon is drawn in 4.1.2 (e.g. just a rectangle in the following, albeit with the same number of x,y coordinates as before)

```
polygon( c(time, rev(time)),
         c(rep(10,length(time)), rep(25,length(time))), 
         col=adjustcolor('dodgerblue', alpha=0.25), border=NA)
```

then the transparent polygon is drawn in R 4.1.2 without issue.

[4.1.2_plot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbRGW.png)

It's no issue for me to go back to R 4.0.3 to get what I need done, however does anyone have any ideas what might be happening here?

Many thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What OS are you using? Is this windows? And what graphics device are you using? Is this in RStudio or base R?

Comment: I can reproduce this with R 4.0.5 (works) and 4.1.0, 4.1.1 (blank).

Comment: @MrFlick I am running in windows, and yes it happens in both R studio and with base R (RGui) plotting. Thankfully the issue has been clarified below.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running R under Windows, then the behaviour that you are seeing is very likely related to [this bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18219) in R 4.1.x. The problem arises only when drawing polygons outside of the plot region, which explains why your attempt with the rectangle succeeded. The bug has been fixed in R-devel (r81114). You can download the development version of R for Windows [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rdevel.html).

Comment: Yes, R-devel solves this issue.

Comment: Wow - thank you both so much for your extremely prompt responses. Very happy it's not just me going crazy.

Comment: I'm on R 4.1.0 and can confirm this fix worked. Thanks!